# Chairs, microphones and a round table

Tags: combinatorics, proof-explanation

There are 92 people sitting around a round table, equally spaced, and also there are 10 microphones on the table in front of 10 different people. Prove that there is a way to rotate the table so that the microphones are positioned in front of 10 people who didn't have a microphone in front of them before the table was turned.

Comment: HINT: the sum of numbers 1 through 9 is 45

Comment: can you explain more, please?

Comment: OK, suppose you say: let's rotate the table by 1 seat ... either there will now be 10 new people with a microphone (in which you are done!), or not. But if not, why will have to be the case? So then let's rotate it by 2 seats (from the original position) ... and keep asking the same question: if we don't get the desired outcome, what would have to be the case?

Answer (score 0):

Label the microphones #1 through #10. How many ways can you rotate the table so that #1 lands on a person who **did** previously have one? How many ways can you rotate the table so that #2 lands on a person who **did** previously have one? Et cetera. Add up your answer for all 10 microphones (or just multiply your answer for #1 by 10) and you get an *upper bound* on the number of **bad** rotations. How does this number compare to the total number of possible rotations (91)?

Comment: do you mean that there is (10*C(91,10)) bad ways?

Comment: No need to use $C(n,k)$. Just identify the number of seats you need to avoid when you rotate the table: Only looking at rotating a single microphone, how many other spots previously had a microphone? That's the number you multiply by 10.